# lftp: how to copy file on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, copy, ftp

How to copy file on remote server using lftp?

Moving files is as easy as using `mv` command, but is there any command equivalent to `cp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the man page:

```
ftpcopy
Obsolete. Use one of the following instead:
    get ftp://... -o ftp://...
    get -O ftp://... file1 file2...
    put ftp://...
    mput ftp://.../*
    mget -O ftp://... ftp://.../*
or  other  combinations  to  get FXP transfer (directly between two ftp
servers).  lftp would fallback to plain copy (via client) if FXP trans-
fer cannot be initiated or ftp:use-fxp is false.
```

so you can copy a file, by doing:

```
get filename -o ftp://user@ftpsite/directory/copyoffile
```

perhaps that will work better than a `put/get` if only because you'll be doing something like FXP, and the server will be using its own local bandwidth

Answer (score 14):

from automated bash script:

```
lftp -u login,password some.host.com -e "put file ; exit "
```

and from lftp's interactive shell:

```
put localFileToBeSent
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking asking how to copy file *on* remote server, not *to* the remote server. The file is already on remote server and I want to have a copy of it with diffrent name and directory. Do I have to use local server, get and put commands for this?

Comment: it looks that way, just looking at the `help` output in `lftp`, there's nothing that even hints at a `copy` command. get/put looks like how you'll have to do it.

Comment: @cpbills afaik it's not a standard command so your will need some luck and support for whateever it is on the other end of your connection.

Comment: how do you mean? get and put are fairly common commands. did you mean to put the comment on my answer? and yeah, a server needs to support fxp in some capacity, but it's an actual solution.

Answer (score 6):

Check the mirror builtin to transfer **one** or **several** files :

*lftp builtin mirror can download or update a whole directory tree. There is also reverse mirror (mirror -R) which uploads or updates a  directory  tree  on  server. Mirror can also synchronize directories between two remote servers, using FXP if available.*

So,

- lftp> mirror -R
  *ftp://from.example.com/directory1* -i file1
  *ftp ://to.example.net/directory2*
- lftp>
  mirror -R
  *ftp://from.example.com/directory1* 
  *ftp://to.example.net/directory2*